# Limit a char property to a certain set of options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

What attribute in C# can limit `public char gender` to `M`, `F` and `O` only, otherwise an error message will appear?

Comment: what about an enum and radio buttons instead of having to validate that the user typed in a valid char, which seems awkward for both sides

Comment: like `public enum Gender { Male, Female, Other }` and property `public Gender UserSelectedGender {get; set;}`

Comment: For everything you can't expect a attribute ... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no such attribute but you can do something like this.

```
public class FOO 
        {
            private char _foo;
            public char foo 
            {
                get { return _foo; }
                set {
                    if (value == 'M' || value == 'F' || value == 'O')
                    {
                        _foo = value;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        throw new Exception("invalid Character");
                    }
              }
            }
        }
```

or you can try ENUM and bind it with interface as you want.

```
public enum Gender 
{ 
    M,
    F,
    O
}
```

and you can use it here

```
public class FOO 
{
   public Gender gender {get;set;} 

}
```

Comment: Thank you. In the first approach, which one is mapped to the SQL table, `_foo` or `foo`?

Comment: foo is the property which is public. where _foo is the private feild.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Enums are really good when you don't need a value to store. When you do need one (which in this case I think you do) I prefer using a public static class as follows:

```
public static class Gender
    {
        public const char Male = 'M';
        public const char Female = 'F';
        public const char Other = 'O';

    }
```

You can then use it similar to an enum but in this case you actually have a value:

```
Gender.Male
```

Comment: Nice solution but the other one is better in my case. Thank you!